# Problema Fatal Error al usar la api rest de Firebase

Tags: php, firebase

**Hola a todos**

Mi problema radica al declarar o iniciar mi variable `$firebase`, la cual contendrá los datos de uso de **Firebase**, para luego acceder a mi base de datos:

```
private $serviceAccount;
private $firebase;
private $database;

function __construct(){
    $this->serviceAccount = ServiceAccount::fromJsonFile(__DIR__  .  '/bot-whatsapp-1d730-firebase-adminsdk-si780-59cb75b81e.json');

    $this->firebase = (new Factory)
        ->withServiceAccount($this->serviceAccount)
        // The following line is optional if the project id in your credentials file
        // is identical to the subdomain of your Firebase project. If you need it,
        // make sure to replace the URL with the URL of your project.
        ->withDatabaseUri('https://bot-whatsapp-1d730.firebaseio.com/')
        ->create();
    $this->database= $this->firebase->getDatabase();
}
```

Pero al ejecutarse esta fracción de código me arroja el error:

> Fatal error: Uncaught GuzzleHttp\Exception\ClientException: Client
>   error: POST https://oauth2.googleapis.com/token resulted in a 400
>   Bad Request response: { "error": "invalid_grant", "error_description":
>   "Invalid JWT: Token must be a short-lived token (60 minutes) and in
>   (truncated...) in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\bot-whatsapp\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Exception\RequestException.php:113
>   Stack trace: #0
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\bot-whatsapp\vendor\guzzlehttp\guzzle\src\Middleware.php(66):
>   GuzzleHttp\Exception\RequestException::create(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Request),
>   Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response)) #1
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\bot-whatsapp\vendor\guzzlehttp\promises\src\Promise.php(203):
>   GuzzleHttp\Middleware::GuzzleHttp{closure}(Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response))
>
> 2
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\bot-whatsapp\vendor\guzzlehttp\promises\src\Promise.php(156):
>   GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise::callHandler(1,
>   Object(GuzzleHttp\Psr7\Response), Array) #3
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\bot-whatsapp\vendor\guzzlehttp\promises\src\TaskQueue.php(47):
>   GuzzleHttp\Promise\Promise::Guzz in
>   C:\xampp\htdocs\bot-whatsapp\vendor\kreait\firebase-php\src\Firebase\Exception\QueryException.php
>   on line 38

Desconozco el paradero de este error, ya que estoy siguiendo los mismos pasos de la api rest de [kreait/firebase](https://firebase-php.readthedocs.io/en/latest/overview.html#usage-example) versión 4.18 para **PHP**.

Ya he comprobado que el .json si se encuentra en la ruta establecida:

> C:\xampp\htdocs\bot-whatsapp/json_firebase/bot-whatsapp-1d730-firebase-adminsdk-si780-59cb75b81e.json

Gracias y espero su pronta ayuda.

Comment: [Revisa este hilo](https://github.com/kreait/firebase-php/issues/163). Debes asegurarte de que estás poniendo la ruta correcta para tu JSON y que realmente ese archivo contiene una autorización válida para conectarte. Supongo que le diste permisos a la API en la consola de Google y que descargaste de allí tu JSON.

Comment: Ya lo he leido, y solucion fue: "Lo sentimos, el problema no estaba en su código. Los tiempos del sistema host estaban mal."  publicada por sdk0794. Y como yo podría cambiar el tiempo de mi sistema host?

Comment: No, no creo. Por lo general `invalid_grant` se refiere  a un problema de permisos. ¿Seguro que estás apuntando correctamente a tu JSON? ¿Sabes dónde lo guardaste cuando lo descargaste de la consola de Google? (Puedes probar poniendo la ruta absoluta del archivo, puede que con `_DIR_` no llegues a él). ¿Creaste el permiso adecuado para el tipo de conexión adecuada. Las API de Google tienen varios tipos de autorizaciones y eso a veces es confuso.

Comment: Oh sobre los permisos no se si son los adecuados, cree mi .json en la opción **Cuenta de Servicios**  y simplemente seleccione la opción **Generar una nueva clave privada**. Sobre la ruta: este se encuentra suelto con mis script, no se encuentra en un sub directorio.

Comment: Pero cuando haces eso, tienes que descargar el JSON, y luego ponerlo en una carpeta de tu proyecto. Debes apuntar a ese JSON **que descargaste y guardaste** en esta parte del código: `$this->serviceAccount = ServiceAccount::fromJsonFile(__DIR__  .  '/bot-whatsapp-1d730-firebase-adminsdk-si780-59cb75b81e.json');` si esto: `__DIR__  .  '/bot-whatsapp-1d730-firebase-adminsdk-si780-59cb75b81e.json'` **no apunta realmente a ese JSON** no estarás autorizado a conectarte. ¿Has verificado eso?  ...

Comment: ... Puedes hacer un `echo __DIR__  .  '/bot-whatsapp-1d730-firebase-adminsdk-si780-59cb75b81e.json';` y verificar que en la ruta que se imprime está **ese archivo que descargaste cuando creaste la cuenta de Servicios**.

Comment: Guarde el .json en una carpeta y luego lo imprimí y me arrojo: C:\xampp\htdocs\bot-whatsapp/json_firebase/bot-whatsapp-1d730-firebase-adminsdk-si780-59cb75b81e.json

Comment: Pero persiste el mismo error presentado.

Comment: Tienes que ir a esta ruta: `C:\xampp\htdocs\bot-whatsapp\json_firebase` y verificar que ahí está el JSON `bot-whatsapp-1d730-firebase-adminsdk-si780-59cb75b81e.json` y que **ese** es el JSON que descargaste de la consola de Google.

Comment: Ya chequee y si existe el archivo en esa ruta, no entiendo porque se produce este error?.

Comment: ¿No has podido resolver nada? Intenta indicarle que es un acceso `offline` con algo como esto: `$this->firebase = (new Factory)
        ->withServiceAccount($this->serviceAccount)->setAccessType('offline')
        ->withDatabaseUri('https://bot-whatsapp-1d730.firebaseio.com/')
        ->create();`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Encontré la solución al mudar mi mi **Script** a un servidor o host. Pero resultaba que mi **netbeans** estaba trabajando a base de **PHP versión 5** y no en **PHP versión 7** la adecuada según la **librería y documentación**.